# jms queue in apache camel rdsl

Tags: apache-camel, jms

```
package com.att.ajsc.deviceeventrouter;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("messageProcessor")
public class MessageProcessor implements Processor {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("-----"+exchange.getIn().getBody());
        exchange.getOut().setBody(exchange.getIn().getBody());
    }

}


        import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;

        import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
        import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
        import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
        import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
        import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent;
        import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
        import org.apache.camel.util.jndi.JndiContext;

        /**
         * An example class for demonstrating some of the basics behind Camel. This
         * example sends some text messages on to a JMS Queue, consumes them and
         * persists them to disk
         */
        public final class CamelJmsToFileExample {

            private CamelJmsToFileExample() {        
            }

            public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
                /*JndiContext jndiContext = new JndiContext();
                jndiContext.bind("myBean", new MyBean());
                jndiContext.bind("mongoClient", new CommonDbConnection());*/
                CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
                ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:61616");
                context.addComponent("test-jms",  JmsComponent.jmsComponentAutoAcknowledge(connectionFactory));
                CustomMessage customMessage = new CustomMessage();
                customMessage.setId("123");
                context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
                    public void configure() {
                        System.out.println("Inside the configure");
                        from("test-jms:queue:test.queue").to("messageProcessor");
                    }
                });
                ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
                context.start();
                template.sendBody("test-jms:queue:test.queue", customMessage);

            }
        }


    pom.xml

    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>EmailService</groupId>
      <artifactId>com.emailService</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <name>emailService</name>
      <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-stream</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                <artifactId>activemq-camel</artifactId>
                <version>5.6.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                <artifactId>activemq-pool</artifactId>
                <version>5.11.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
                <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
                <version>3.4.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-mongodb</artifactId>
                <version>2.13.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-integration-mongodb</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency> 
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
                <artifactId>camel-spring-boot</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.1</version>
            </dependency> 
      </dependencies>
    </project>




exception am facing :




 SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
    Inside the configure
    Exception in thread "main" org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1 at: >>> To[messageProcessor] <<< in route: Route(route1)[[From[test-jms:queue:test.queue]] -> [To[messa... because of No endpoint could be found for: messageProcessor, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.
        at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1028)
        at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:185)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRoute(DefaultCamelContext.java:841)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.startRouteDefinitions(DefaultCamelContext.java:2895)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStartCamel(DefaultCamelContext.java:2618)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.access$000(DefaultCamelContext.java:167)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2467)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext$2.call(DefaultCamelContext.java:2463)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doWithDefinedClassLoader(DefaultCamelContext.java:2486)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.doStart(DefaultCamelContext.java:2463)
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.start(DefaultCamelContext.java:2432)
        at CamelJmsToFileExample.main(CamelJmsToFileExample.java:37)
    Caused by: org.apache.camel.NoSuchEndpointException: No endpoint could be found for: messageProcessor, please check your classpath contains the needed Camel component jar.
        at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:81)
        at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.resolveEndpoint(RouteDefinition.java:200)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:107)
        at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRouteContext.resolveEndpoint(DefaultRouteContext.java:113)
        at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.resolveEndpoint(SendDefinition.java:62)
        at org.apache.camel.model.SendDefinition.createProcessor(SendDefinition.java:56)
        at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.makeProcessor(ProcessorDefinition.java:505)
        at org.apache.camel.model.ProcessorDefinition.addRoutes(ProcessorDefinition.java:217)
        at org.apache.camel.model.RouteDefinition.addRoutes(RouteDefinition.java:1025)
        ... 12 more
```

Hi am facing the above exception when send data from jms queue to processor can any one help to resolve this issue.
Can any one suggest how to implement jms Queue in apache camel java RDSL.
Any pointer will be really helpful to me..

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The message processor is a string, eg

```
 from("test-jms:queue:test.queue").to("messageProcessor");
```

Which makes Camel assume its a component with that name and its not, so change it to

```
from("test-jms:queue:test.queue").process(new Processor() ... );
```

And inline a processor where you can do something with the message, or if you just want a quick test then use a log endpoint

```
 from("test-jms:queue:test.queue").to("log:hello");
```

Also beware that the `start` method on `CamelContext` is not blocking. See this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/running-camel-standalone-and-have-it-keep-running.html